# Why am I getting a 500 Error when using PayPal uses IPN to WooCommerce?

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-ipn

I'm using WooCommerce version 3.3.5 and I'm trying to get the IPN to work so that my orders get updated.

I added https://example.com/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Paypal  as my notification URL in PayPal.

I'm currently getting a 500 error "PayPal IPN Request Failure" when the order is processed.

What am I doing wrong or what do I have to do to fix this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Make sure wordpress debug mode enabled and check the debug.log file, located in the wp-content folder. This should show the reason at least.

Comment: Did you solved the problem? I'm asking because I have the same issue.